# how to control selected state of a button?

Tags: uibutton, state, selected

Ok so i have a button.. i have specified what i wanna see when the button is selected in the attributes section of the Xcode.It is woking properly. But in case i want to give options such that every time the button is pressed ,  it displays different content, where i will be specifying the array of contents. How is it possible?
For eg, displaying one of the 52 cards randomly at a time.

I am trying the homework 0 which is given in the Stanford University iOS Developement videos.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can get random number using

```
-(int)getRandomNumberBetween:(int)from to:(int)to {

    return (int)from + arc4random() % (to-from+1);
}
```

And on button press

```
-(IBAction)yourBtnPress:(id)sender
{
    int randomNumber = [self getRandomNumberBetween:0 to:51];
    //Get Your card from your card array
    [yourCardAry objectAtIndex:randomNumber];

    //Then display it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

```
- (void)ButtonAction {

    int randNumber =arc4random()%yourArray.count;

    /// show your content as like [yourArray objectAtIndex:randNumber];
}
```

Hope it will helps you..

Answer (score 0):

You can generate Random number something like 
`int randomNumber1 =  1 + random() % 100;`